# Scheme procedure to replace elements in a list

Tags: list, scheme

I am trying to create a procedure in scheme which replaces a certain element in a list with another element

```
(define (replace var player list)
  (if (null? list)
      '()
     (if (list? (car list))
                (cons (replace var player (car list))          
                      (replace var player (cdr list))
          (if (equal? var (car list))
              (cons player (replace var player (cdr list)))
              (cons (car list) (replace var player (cdr list)))
          ))))
```

Currently the procedure does not replace any elements.
This is the input list

```
'(q w (e r (t x)) y u i (o (x)) p x a s d)
```

I would like to replace the 'x' elements in that list with 'y'.

This is the desired output

```
'(q w (e r (t y)) y u i (o (y)) p y a s d)
```

We have tried

```
(replace_by 'x 'y '(q w (e r (t x)) y u i (o (x)) p x a s d)
```

but it does not seem to be working

Comment: This code seems to be functional, at least for the given list (though I am sure it could be structured better). There is a missing ')' to close the first `cons` i.e. (replace var player (cdr list)) **)** and there is no reason to put `replace_by` in the code, only `replace` is needed

Comment: Super dup alert

Comment: @ghosh -- that does not look like a good dupe candidate to me. Here OP had a minor problem that led to code not working. I addressed this in my answer: the misplaced parenth caused no output. But worse for the dupe you propose: the algorithm described in the only answer there does not descend into nested lists, which OP code here does.

Comment: @exnihilo np you are probably correct but the question is so common/basic/trivial is has 99.9% been answered already somewhere, most likely even on the site..

Comment: @ghosh -- this is fundamentally a debugging question, and finding another question with missing parentheses should be quite easy, but not at all useful. But OP code had a deeper issue of generality, in that it was able to replace _atom_ elements in nested lists when the parentheses were fixed, but it could not replace _list_ elements (not even null list elements `'()`). You might be able to find a dupe for that more rare issue, but IAC the proposed dupe is definitely not addressing any of the issues here.

Answer (score 1):

The posted code is missing one parenth at the end, and has a misplaced parenth. The first `cons` expression needs to be closed by a parenth:

```
(define (replace var player list)
  (if (null? list)
      '()
     (if (list? (car list))
         (cons (replace var player (car list))          
               (replace var player (cdr list)))
         (if (equal? var (car list))
             (cons player (replace var player (cdr list)))
             (cons (car list) (replace var player (cdr list)))))))
```

After these corrections, the OP code works for nested lists where the item to be replaced is a non-list. But, it fails when the item to be replaced is a list. This is because list elements encountered in the input are never checked for equality against `var`. Note also that it is a bad idea to use `list` as a formal parameter in Scheme functions; this shadows the built-in `list` function.

Here is an implementation that will replace both atoms and lists in the input list. Before checking whether the input is an atom, the function checks for equality with `old`. If the `old` value is not `equal?` to the current `head` value, then the function checks whether the current `head` value is an atom. If it is, then that atom (which was not `equal?` to `old`) is consed onto the result of calling `replace` on the `tail`; note that empty lists are considered atoms (`'()` is both a list *and* an atom) and have already been handled at this stage. Otherwise, the current `head` is a non-empty list, and the function descends into both the `head` and the `tail`.

Here `atom?` is used to distinguish between non-empty lists and atoms, with `'()` being considered an atom. Some Schemes include a definition for `atom?`, but it is not in R5RS or R6RS Standard Scheme. You can define it yourself if needed:

```
(define (atom? x)
  (not (pair? x)))
```

Or you could just use `(not (pair? head))` in place of `(atom? head)` in the code below, which uses `atom?` because the name seems more descriptive. A `let` expression is used to reduce the number of calls to `car` and `cdr`, and to clarify the intent of the recursive calls to `replace`:

```
(define (replace old new xs)
  (if (null? xs)
      xs
      (let ((head (car xs))
            (tail (cdr xs)))
        (cond ((equal? head old)
               (cons new (replace old new tail)))
              ((atom? head)
               (cons head (replace old new tail)))
              (else
               (cons (replace old new head)
                     (replace old new tail)))))))
```

Here are some sample interactions:

```
> (replace 'a 'x '(1 2 a 3 4 a))
(1 2 x 3 4 x)

> (replace 'a 'x '(1 2 a (3 4 a (5 a (a (a)) 6 a) ()) a))
(1 2 x (3 4 x (5 x (x (x)) 6 x) ()) x)

> (replace '() 'x '(1 2 a (3 4 a (5 a (a (a)) 6 a) ()) a))
(1 2 a (3 4 a (5 a (a (a)) 6 a) x) a)

> (replace '(5 a (a (a)) 6 a) 'x '(1 2 a (3 4 a (5 a (a (a)) 6 a) ()) a))
(1 2 a (3 4 a x ()) a)

> (replace '(5 a (a (a)) 6 a) '(x (x x)) '(1 2 a (3 4 a (5 a (a (a)) 6 a) ()) a))
(1 2 a (3 4 a (x (x x)) ()) a)
```

Comment: Sorry about the parenthesis. Thank you for the answer